# Setting airplane mode does not completely work

Tags: android

I've written the code below to set the phone into airplane mode to save power. The devices is being used as a WiFi-Hotspot to relay data from some sensors in a village in Indonesia. The sensors send their data at the same time so I just need to come out of airplane mode for five minutes at midnight and then reenter airplane mode.

The problem is the cellular radio is not shut off and the airplane icon does not appear. Though the the phone reports its status as airplane_mode on, it is still possible to call it. Other widgets in the marketplace seem to fare no better. I've tried "Airplane Mode Wi-Fi Tool". It too can not get the airplane icon to appear nor disable cell radio. When watching LogCat while using the device settings to go to Airplane mode, I can see that much more is happening than when trying from the program.

If I load my program on a Droid, this code works as expected. `AIRPLANE_MODE_RADIOS` is set to `cell, bluetooth, wifi`.

The offending device is a Samsung Galaxy 5, I5500 tested with:

-Froyo 2.2 build FROYO.UYJP2
-Froyo 2.2.1 build FROYO.UYJPE

One interesting side note: if I programmatically set airplane mode and then power cycle the device, it comes up in full airplane mode, rejects incoming calls etc.

Do others have similar stories with this or other devices? Is there a way to specifically turn off cell only?

```
public static void setAirplaneMode(Context context, boolean status) {

    boolean isAM = Settings.System.getInt(context.getContentResolver(),
            Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) != 0;

    String radios = Settings.System.getString(context.getContentResolver(),
            Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_RADIOS);

    //This line is reporting all radios affected but annunciator does not seem to think so. Does not show airplane
    Wake.logger("Airplane mode is: " + isAM + " changing to " + status + " For radios: " + radios, false);

    // It appears Airplane mode should only be toggled. Don't reset to
    // current state.
    if (isAM && !status) {
        Settings.System.putInt(context.getContentResolver(),
                Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
        intent.putExtra("state", 0);
        context.sendBroadcast(intent);
        return;
    }
    if (!isAM && status) {
        Settings.System.putInt(context.getContentResolver(),
                Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 1);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
        intent.putExtra("state", 1);
        context.sendBroadcast(intent);
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: So your saying if you set airplane mode then restart the phone it works? This sounds device specific, the work around is simply do just that! You can have a broadcast receiver that will start your app back up after the phone turns itself back on.

Comment: Correct. However, the device will be unattended. It's going to relay data at set times from a location without power. We'll have large batteries or inexpensive solar. Is it possible to configure a device to power up periodically? I was thinking it might be possible to apply power for 10 min/day via USB to start and stop the phone. Does n't work though. In any case I figured my problem. See answer.

Answer (score 4):

Classic bit twister error. The extra data argument in the broadcast intent needed to be true/false, not 1/0. Ugh!!!

```
    intent.putExtra("state", true);  //Not 1!!
```

One phone worked another didn't. Now both do.

Comment: Ahh, thanks ! Every other question has this wrong, it needs to be a boolean, not an int !